# communication service and Activity through global variable

Tags: android, android-activity, service

Hi I have a service running and fetch location every 30 seconds (as it showns in code(1)) I want to store location to be available at anytime 
my aproach is to store as a global variable within the application context (as it showns in code(2) and code(1)) so, later I can get it from MainActivity as shown in code(3).

code (1)

```
 public class LocationService extends Service{

 @Override
 public void onCreate(){

 // I have a service here from where I can get Location every 30 secs
  {
   Location location=// from android api get Location every 30 secs
  ((App)getApplication()).setLocation(location);
  }
 }

}
```

(2)

```
public class App extends Application{
Location mLocation;

public void setLocation(Location location){
  mLocation=location;
 }

public Location getLocation(){
  return mLocation;
 }
```

(3)

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity{
 @Override
 public void onCreate(){
 Location location=((App)getApplication()).getLocation();
 }

}
```

My Question is that aproach valid?. I saw that usually is used either broadcast or bind service and activity, I have never seen to share gloabal variable between service and activity, ¿why?.

Any discussion is wellcome.

Comment: The above use case is already handled by little-fluffy-location-library. You can download the sample from the below link 
https://code.google.com/p/little-fluffy-location-library/

Comment: I know there are backed aproach to do that I just know pros and cons of sharing global vars between activity and service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You approach is a valid one. according to the [android developer site](http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/framework.html#3) you have the following options:

- put data inside an intent
- singleton class
- a public static field/method
- a HashMap or WeakReferences to Objects
- use sharedPreferences
- put into the database

Each one of these approaches depends on the situation. In my opinion it is better to store the location in a static field, and expose a static getter method for that field in your Service.